# How to count row in SQL SERVER 2012 using sys.partitions

Tags: sql-server, count

I try to implement some of the faster ways for counting row number rather than the `COUNT()` that I'm using right now. However even with the simple example that I use to get a grast of how to get used of the `sys.partitions` abilities I am not able to get the result I'm expecting.

I have table `[dbo].[Client] and I take the number of the records inside the table simply by:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Client]
```

and the result is:

```
(No column name)
40306
```

Now I'm trying to count the records from the same table getting use of the `sys.partitions` using this example I found online and modifying it to match my table :

```
SELECT
sch.name AS dbo,
SysTab.Name AS Client,
sch.name + '.' + SysTab.name AS QualifiedName,
SUM(
CASE
WHEN (Parti.index_id < 2) AND (alloUni.type = 1) THEN Parti.rows
ELSE 0
END
) AS Rows
FROM sys.partitions AS Parti
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units AS alloUni ON Parti.partition_id = alloUni.container_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS SysTab ON SysTab.object_id = Parti.Object_ID
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS sch ON sch.schema_id = SysTab.schema_id
GROUP BY SysTab.name, sch.name
```

And even though I get a result there's two problems for me here. The result is:

```
dbo Client                  QualifiedName              Rows
dbo MSreplication_options   dbo.MSreplication_options   3
dbo spt_fallback_db         dbo.spt_fallback_db         0
dbo spt_fallback_dev        dbo.spt_fallback_dev        0
dbo spt_fallback_usg        dbo.spt_fallback_usg        0
dbo spt_monitor             dbo.spt_monitor             1
dbo spt_values              dbo.spt_values              2508
```

And first - I really don't know what this whole data is all about, my `SQL` knowledge is very moderate but I want to start using a faster counting since sometimes for very big tables I get huge delay just for this action and also, looking at the result in fact I don't see anything which I can use to get the actual count as the `COUNT(*)` is returning and which I actually need.

In short - instead of all this information that for me is useless I would liek to get something similar to the output of calling just `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Take a look here http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/02/count-number-rows-table-sql-server/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    TableName = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id) + '.' + t.Name,
    RowCount = p.rows
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

**Update:** if you want to get the values for a specific table, replace

```
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%'
```

with whatever table name you want:

```
WHERE 
    t.object_id = OBJECT_ID('[MyDBName].[dbo].[Client]')
```

Comment: I just don't understand where I should pass the table name and how exactly I should do it. Using my example if I'm using `[MyDBName].[dbo].[Client]` how to pass it in your example in order to get a working code?

Comment: @Leron: updated my code - not sure if this will work across database boundaries - possibly you'll have to go to the `MyDBName` database first, and then execute this script with `WHERE t.object_id = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Client]')` in the `WHERE` clause ....

Comment: In fact I don't have to use `USE MyDBName` I can go with the full table name (containing the DB name) and it's working correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RowCount'.

Comment: @ismailyavuz: what **version** (2000, 2005, 2008, etc.) and which **edition** (Compact, Express, Web, Standard, Enterprise) of SQL Server??

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise. I've replaced the select clause like this and that worked well: TableName = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id) + '.' + t.Name,
    p.rows,partition_number

Answer (score 1):

You can use either:

**SQL Server 2005/2008**

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(i.id) [Table_Name], i.rowcnt [Row_Count]
FROM sys.sysindexes i WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE i.indid in (0,1)
ORDER BY i.rowcnt desc
```

**SQL Server 2000**

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(i.id) [Table_Name], i.rows [Row_Count]
FROM sysindexes i (NOLOCK)
WHERE i.indid in (0,1)
ORDER BY i.rows desc
```

[Source](http://dbatipster.blogspot.pt/2009/08/get-row-counts-fast.html)

However, I should note that this syntax is not standard and depends on your DB type and DB version (i.e. you will be locking your application to run only in a specific vendor database version.)

To maintain database compatibility, you should stick with the standard `COUNT(*)` aggregate.